# changing a list of variable names in a global macro to factors

Tags: stata

I would like to change a list of variable names in an existing global macro to factors without generating a new global macro, i.e. changing the contents of the existing macro

For example, I have the following list of variable names:

```
global list x1 x2 x3
```

My desired result is

```
global list i.x1 i.x2 i.x3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
global list x1 x2 x3

foreach v of global list {
    local new `new' i.`v'
}

global list `new'
```